# How to open a webview from imagebutton?

Tags: android, webview, imagebutton

I have three buttons in a fragment that when the user clicks on one it'll open a specific webpage within the application. When I try to run this code on the phone it crashes when I try to access the tab.

My .java class is right here:

```
public class SocialMediaFragment extends Fragment {

public ImageButton fbbutton;
public ImageButton twbutton;
public ImageButton igbutton;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_socialmedia, container, false);

    fbbutton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fbbutton);
    twbutton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.twbutton);
    igbutton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.igbutton);

    fbbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/universityofhouston"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });

    twbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("website"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);

        }});

    igbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("website"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);

        }});
    return rootView;

}
}
```

And here is the fragment (XML) file I am using:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/uhwallpaper">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fbbutton"
        android:background="@drawable/fb"
        android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/twbutton"
        android:background="@drawable/twitter"
        android:layout_above="@+id/igbutton"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fbbutton"
        android:layout_marginStart="43dp" />



    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/igbutton"
        android:background="@drawable/instagram"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fbbutton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp" />



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/socialslogan"
        android:background="@drawable/slogan_social"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this is fixable! If you need any more information let me know.

Here is my error report:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at info.teammumu.cougarcardapp.SocialMediaFragment.onCreateView(SocialMediaFragment.java:28)
```

Comment: post your LogCat message, what kind of error?

Comment: of course! I edited the post to include it

Comment: Your `fbbutton ` should be inited before call the method.

Comment: Just add `fbbutton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xxxxx);` before setOnClickListener().

Comment: I have updated the code to show I have done the steps, but i keep getting the same error and the application is crashing

Comment: Using **Elenasys** answer are you getting same error? Please update logcat if you are getting something new!

Comment: same error:  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
            at info.teammumu.cougarcardapp.SocialMediaFragment.onCreateView(SocialMediaFragment.java:35)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: I didn't know that was unacceptable because I use this site and a lot of posts use it... and the "advance" thing was a typo FYI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with these guys:

```
fbbutton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fbbutton);
twbutton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.twbutton);
igbutton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.igbutton);
```

they're supposed to be:

```
fbbutton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fbbutton);
twbutton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.twbutton);
igbutton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.igbutton);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 1) You are inside a fragment, so your elements must be defined inside the layout `fragment_socialmedia.xml`

```
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_socialmedia, container, false);

   mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
    fbbutton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fbbutton);
    twbutton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.twbutton);
    igbutton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.igbutton);
```

#### 2), add `@override` to the `onClick` method:

```
 fbbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/universityofhouston"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);


        }});
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Just to make sure, just add @Override correct? I still get the same error.

Comment: I am still getting the crash. By "elements defined inside the layout" is the XML code i provided incorrect?

Comment: fragment_socialmedia.xml doesn´t have the elements drawer_layout and list_slidermenu, remember "your elements must be defined inside the layout fragment_socialmedia.xml"

Comment: I removed them because I found they were unnecessary for the code, but I still have the same problem...

Comment: Any progress? I have gone a little crazy with this code!

Answer (score 0):

Your fbbutton is never assigned. It is null as it is by default. Initialize it just like other views from your layout via findViewById().

Comment: i think I initialized it (check code above) but I still get the same error unfortunately

Comment: I cannot check now but I think the inflate method has to be called before you init views. The findviewbyid can return null in some cases. Try moving the rootview assigning to the start of your method

Comment: I have moved it before the init views but I still get the same error and the app still crashes

Answer (score 0):

First of all I believe that it should work the way Elenasys is supposing it.
Another try would be to change your layout xml and attach the method to call within the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/uhwallpaper">

<ImageButton
    android:onClick="myMethod"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fbbutton"
    android:background="@drawable/fb"
    android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you have to write a method inside your activity holding your fragment like this:

```
/**
* Method inside the activity holding your fragment.
*/
public void myMethod(View view){
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/universityofhouston"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

Does it help?

Comment: It's not working BUT I was able to tweak the code so I don't have worry about the list_slidermenu and drawer_layout anymore. They weren't needed. I updated the error too. It still is giving me the same error: null object reference

Comment: can you please update your current code, because in your question you are still using getActivity() which won't work for sure ? :)