# URI.parse and imagebutton error

Tags: java, android, uri, imagebutton

The code is meant to open a webview when the user clicks on a button, but I get the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void     android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at info.teammumu.cougarcardapp.SocialMediaFragment.onCreateView(SocialMediaFragment.java:28)
```

for the java code:

```
public class SocialMediaFragment extends Fragment {

public ImageButton fbbutton;
public ImageButton twbutton;
public ImageButton igbutton;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_socialmedia, container, false);

fbbutton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fbbutton);
twbutton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.twbutton);
igbutton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.igbutton);

fbbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/universityofhouston"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
});

twbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("website"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);

    }});

igbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("website"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);

    }});
return rootView;
}}
```

I asked a question like this before, but it was never answered or maybe I didn't understand it...[How to open a webview from imagebutton?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29014167/4534028)
Thanks to anyone who can help with this! I have been trying to solve it for the past few days but no success. It crashes and I can't open the tab whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rootView` instead of `getActivity()` to access views from Fragment layout which is returned from `onCreateView` :

```
fbbutton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fbbutton);
twbutton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.twbutton);
.....
```

Because `getActivity` return context of Activity in which current fragment is added so calling `getActivity().findViewById(<ID>)` means accessing view from Activity Layout instead of Fragment.

Comment: Now my question is, how do I keep the webview inside of the application, because it is exiting the application to go to the website.

Comment: @daybis13: add WebView to Fragment layout see following example [Android WebView example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/)

Answer (score 0):

if you have the buttons in the same view that you are inflating then you should change these lines :

```
fbbutton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fbbutton);
twbutton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.twbutton);
igbutton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.igbutton);
```

to be like :

```
fbbutton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fbbutton);
twbutton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.twbutton);
igbutton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.igbutton);
```